# Why is the line find_element_by_css_selector crossed in my code?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, pycharm

This is an image of how the code looks and I don't even know if works despite the crossed line

string = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h2[class="hdl9e2-0 bNcmDq"]')

It doesn't show but in Pycharm the line find_element_by_css_selector is all crossed.

Comment: can you show the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its crossed out because find_element_by_css_selector is deprecated, you should use find_element and provide it with the parameters By.CSS_SELECTOR and the css selector you want to search for.
E.g:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".nav")
```

Should be used instead of:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")
```